# Spring DispatcherServlet does not hits the controller after refresh

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new to spring mvc and I am working on a project which was earlier working on servlets in place of spring. In my code I am using DispatcherServlet to handle two ajax calls,one of which works fine while the other which works for the first time when I launch server but does not hits the controller again when I refresh the page.This means the problem is not in the spring environment but in how the second controller interacts with spring(because it works absolutely fine in servlets).

here is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>final</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>datapage.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

and here is my Dispatcher-servlet file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd"
        >
   <context:component-scan
        base-package="raga.controller" />



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

here is my /CompanyGsonObjects controller

```
    @Controller
public class sping {


@RequestMapping(value="/CompanyGsonObjects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void CompanyGsonObjects(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException, SQLException{

    System.out.println("abc");
JQueryDataTableParamModel param = DataTablesParamUtility.getParam(request);

String sEcho = param.sEcho;
int iTotalRecords; // total number of records (unfiltered)
int iTotalDisplayRecords; //value will be set when code filters companies by keyword

iTotalRecords = DataRepository.GetCompanies().size();
List<Company> companies = new LinkedList<Company>();
for(Company c : DataRepository.GetCompanies()){
    if( c.getName().toLowerCase().contains(param.sSearch.toLowerCase())
        ||
        c.getAddress().toLowerCase().contains(param.sSearch.toLowerCase())
        ||
        c.getProxy().toLowerCase().contains(param.sSearch.toLowerCase())
        ||
        c.getTown().toLowerCase().contains(param.sSearch.toLowerCase()))
    {
        companies.add(c); // add company that matches given search criterion
    }
}
iTotalDisplayRecords = companies.size();// number of companies that match search criterion should be returned

final int sortColumnIndex = param.iSortColumnIndex;
final int sortDirection = param.sSortDirection.equals("asc") ? -1 : 1;

Collections.sort(companies, new Comparator<Company>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Company c1, Company c2) {    
        switch(sortColumnIndex){
        case 0:
            return c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName()) * sortDirection;
        case 1:
            return c1.getAddress().compareTo(c2.getAddress()) * sortDirection;
        case 2:
            return c1.getTown().compareTo(c2.getTown()) * sortDirection;
        case 3:
            return c1.getProxy().compareTo(c2.getProxy()) * sortDirection;  
        }
        return 0;
    }
});

if(companies.size()< param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength) {
    companies = companies.subList(param.iDisplayStart, companies.size());
} else {
    companies = companies.subList(param.iDisplayStart, param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength);
}

try {   
    JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject();     
    jsonResponse.addProperty("sEcho", sEcho);
    jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
    jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalDisplayRecords", iTotalDisplayRecords);         
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    jsonResponse.add("aaData", gson.toJsonTree(companies));

    response.setContentType("application/Json");
    response.getWriter().print(jsonResponse.toString());

} catch (JsonIOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
}

}
}
```

Now, as i have told you this is not working, but there is something else which I found interesting,it is if i give the complete url pattern in servlet mapping, t works fine.for example if i write

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CompanyGsonObjects</url-pattern> // the call which does not work when i use / instead of CompanyGsonObjects
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring</url-pattern> // the call which works
</servlet-mapping>
```

as i have told you the request with url /spring works fine whether I use "/" or "/spring" but request wirh url /CompanyGsonObjects does not works when I use "/".
If anyone can suggest something, please help.Thanks for reading anyways.

Comment: It would be nice that you say what the requested URLs (first time and second time) look like. I'm sorry but my cristal ball is currently out of use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late answer but I found what was the problem. Actually the spring controller was working fine, the only problem was that I was invoking the controller from a javascript file which was in other folder. Now first time it runs fine but after I hit the controller, the control goes away to spring dispatcher, which cannot locate my javascript file because it keeps looking for it in the path I specified for controller.

to correct this just needed to change my url to *.html in web.xml and add .html in the end of the @requestmapping value and also in the end of url where you make the call in javascript.